# How to encode quotes in HTML body?

Tags: html, xhtml, encoding, character-encoding

Should I encode quotes (such as " and ' -> `&rdquo;` and `&rsquo;`) in my HTML body (e.g. convert `<p>Matt's Stuff</p>` to `<p>Matt&rsquo;s Stuff</p>`)? I was under the impression I should, but a co-worker said that it was no big deal. I'm dubious but I can't find anything that says it is forbidden. Am I mistaken? Is it a best-practice to encode? Or is it simply useless?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Encoding quotation marks (") is in practice only needed if the're inside an attribute, however for the HTML code to be correct (passing HTML validation), you should always encode quotation marks as `&quot;`.

Apostrophes (') don't need escaping in HTML. In XHTML they should be encoded as `&apos;`.

Comment: `&apos;` is OK — but only as long as you don't plan to serve the document as **text/html** (which most people do as they want Internet Explorer to render the pages). http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_16

Comment: @Quentin - i'm just noting that your link says to use  &#39; for Apostrophes (') instead of &apos;
Thanks !

Comment: @danfromisrael — Yes, please reread my comment "only as long as you don't plan to serve the document as text/html".

Comment: i know i just thought it's better to be here on comments instead of trying to understand it from the link... thanks again!

Comment: &quot; is only valuable for indicating someone is 5'11" tall or similar situations. You should be using &ldquo; and &rdquo; for double quotations as they are more typographically correct. Here's a nice write-up: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/typographically-correct-punctuation/

Comment: @Jereme: Yes, that would be optimal, but not all fonts have all characters. Sometimes it's more important that everyone can read it than that it looks slightly better for most.

Comment: @Guffa: Correct quotation marks are optimal; with them, it is important to choose optimal fonts, as well. I would rather provide the best possible experience to the vast majority of users over a sub-optimal experience to all users.

Comment: @Jereme: Yes, of course, but there are two big problems with that. You have no control over what fonts are installed on the client computer, and it might not be your choise as a web developer to ignore a segment of the visitors.

Comment: @Guffa: It is certainly a project-specific choice. What percent of users would we be missing the requisite characters? I would guess that most users these days are using browsers that can load web fonts and that in most other cases the system fonts are of high enough quality that falling back on the default sans-serif would include them, as well. So are we talking about less than 1% of users? That would be my pull-it-out-of-thin-air guess. Seems like something worth knowing, though!

Answer (score 6):

If you want your markup to be parsable as XML, you'll want to encode the following:

```
& => &amp;
< => &lt;
> => &gt;
" => &quot;
' => &apos;
```

Definitely do this in attributes whether you're trying to make your code XML compliant or not.

Answer (score 3):

Typicaly such isn't necessary unless you're placing such values into a tag's attribute (or other places where having quote marks would throw off parsing). In regular body text un-encoded will work fine.

```
<img src="..." alt="A &quot;quote mark&quot; in an alt attribute" />
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you only need to use character references for quotes (single or double) if you want to use them inside an attribute value declaration that uses the same quotes for the value declaration:

```
title="The sign says &quot;Matt's Stuff&quot;"
title='The sign says "Matt&#39;s Stuff"'
```

Both title values are *`The sign says "Matt's Stuff"`*.