# HTML quotes inside of quotes inside of quotes

Tags: php, html, quotes

So I am writing HTML and I know if I need to put quotes inside other quotes I can use "" and '' but what if I need more than 2 sets. quotes inside quotes inside quotes. Are there more quote types I can use?

Comment: Please post examples of what you have and what you want to have and why

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode quotes in HTML body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664208/encode-quotes-in-html-body)

Answer (score 1):

Quotes only have special meaning in HTML when you need to delimit attribute values.

If you need to represent a quote character inside an attribute value delimited with quote characters, use a character reference: `&quot;`.

Nested quotes have no significance, so you can keep using `&quot;` (although it doesn't make much sense in English to do do).

Answer (score 0):

You put the php tag so I guess you have troubles inside your php code.

Here is an example in PHP :

```
$var = "this is a sentance : \"test sentence with ' which is a quote\" END ";
```

you will have `this is a sentance : "test sentence with ' which is a quote" END` in $var