# Ruby: Send string with double quotes to Google Alerts

Tags: ruby, string, double-quotes

Here's my piece of code in Ruby:

```
require 'galerts'

manager = Galerts::Manager.new('blah@gmail.com', 'password')

new_alert = manager.create("sam", {

:frequency => Galerts::RT,
  :domain => 'com',
  :language => Galerts::LANGUAGE,
  :sources => [Galerts::NEWS],
  :how_many => Galerts::BEST_RESULTS,
  :region => Galerts::ANYWHERE,
  :delivery => Galerts::EMAIL
  }
)
```

As you see from the code, this code sends a string to Google Alers in a form of `sam` and it is actually working good. Now, the issue is that I want to send it as `"sam"`, not `sam`. Would you have suggestions?

I tried:
`"""sam"""`, `""sam""`, `%q(sam)`, `"\"sam\""`, etc. Nothing works by now.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following two options (neither throws an error) and see which produces the best output for Google Alerts.

First, try URL encoding (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the quotation marks by replacing the inside quotes with `%22` as follows:

```
"%22sam%22"
```

Another option would be HTML encoding ([Encode quotes in HTML body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664208/encode-quotes-in-html-body)) by replacing the inside quotes with `&quot;`

```
"&quot;sam&quot;"
```

Comment: Nope, they're shown at Google Alerts list as `"&quot;sam&quot;"` and `%22sam%22`

Comment: I wonder if this just may be a limitation of Google Alerts then, i.e. not allowing any special characters.

Comment: That's the thing, it is possible to send keys manually by typing `"sam"`, and it will show `"sam"`. I still incline to that it is possible to send the key the way I want...