# What is the best use of php htmlentities() function while I have double and single quote in my string?

Tags: php

Please consider the following examples:

`{assign var="title_short" value="\"Think win-win.\" - A quote by whom? » MCQ Academy"}`

**Example 1:**

```
<a title="{$title_short|htmlentities}" href="{$story_url}">{$title_short|htmlentities}</a>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<a title="{$title_short|htmlentities}" href="{$story_url}">{$title_short}</a>
```

Which use of htmlentities() function should I follow when I have double and/or single quote in my string?

Comment: Well they would only ever break the `title` attribute. In text context, not really necessary. Also, `htmlspecialchars` would suffice to ensure your attributes are not broken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode quotes in HTML body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664208/how-to-encode-quotes-in-html-body)

Comment: I did update the question. Actually the `htmlentities()` require in the `title` attribute. I want to know, is it also good practice to use within in the `<a></a>` tag?

Comment: Every value that you don't know in advance should be properly encoded as HTML when it is included in HTML context. Otherwise you can generate invalid HTML and it is vulnerable to injections. Think what happens if `title` contains something like `"><script>...`.

Comment: Quotes are only really a concern _inside tag attributes_. Whatever quotes you have in between the _opening_ and _closing_ tags is fine. The special characters `<>&` are more of a concern across the board, and are best converted to avoid misinterpretation. N.B. Characters like `»` are also fine inside attributes without conversion to entities. You may want to update your post's tags with reference to whatever templating engine you're using, as this has little to do with vanilla PHP.

Comment: @axiac I know the values of string variable. Not worry about XSS.

Comment: In theory, `&`, `"`, `<` and `>` should always be encoded in HTML. In practice, it makes sense to encode `"` only in the attributes (assuming they are enclosed in `"`). `<` and `>` should be encoded outside HTML tags; it does not help to encode them in attributes. `&` should be encoded everywhere (including in the URLs used in `href` or `src`). A `'` not encoded cannot cause trouble anywhere (assuming, again, that the attributes are quoted using `"`, as it is recommended).